# I am trying to find the current logged in user information in Ultimate Membership Pro

Tags: php, wordpress, membership

I am using the wordpress plugin Ultimate Membership Pro to manage my website subscriptions. Is there a way to figure out who the active user is that is signed in? I looked through the plugin files to see if there was anything code that accomplished this but I didn't see anything.

Comment: You want to check membership level

Comment: Not necessarily membership level. I want to check there username while they are on the website. Is there some kind of shortcode to check the username?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using `wp_get_current_user()`

Check the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) about it